# How can I convert a Raw Data file of Audio in .Wav with python

Tags: python-2.7

Knowing some things  like : Encoding : 16bit pcm, Byte order Little Endian , Channels : 1 Mono, Start offset : 0 bytes , Amount to import : 100% and Sample rate 16000 Hz.

That Characteristics were given by *Audacity*, in that way I can hear it in this program.

But I want to do it in Python code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, can do this using the wave library or wavio api

https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html

Open The wave file in write binary mode.

wave.open(file[, mode])
If file is a string, open the file by that name, otherwise treat it as a seekable file-like object. mode can be any of

'w', 'wb'
Write only mode.

Set all the parameter of the wav file as you have shared w.r.t the audacity

Wave_write.setparams(tuple)
The tuple should be (nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname), with values valid for the set*() methods. Sets all parameters.

Open the raw file in binary mode and pass the data to these function.

Wave_write.writeframesraw(data)¶
Write audio frames, without correcting nframes.

Wave_write.writeframes(data)
Write audio frames and make sure nframes is correct.

once done close the file handle.

Wave_write.close()
Make sure nframes is correct, and close the file if it was opened by wave. This method is called upon object collection.

I hope you can implement the python code based on these description.

Answer (score 5):

Read bytes (`rb`) from the raw file and write bytes (`wb`) to WAV after setting the header. See [wave](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html) module

```
import wave

with open("sound.raw", "rb") as inp_f:
    data = inp_f.read()
    with wave.open("sound.wav", "wb") as out_f:
        out_f.setnchannels(1)
        out_f.setsampwidth(2) # number of bytes
        out_f.setframerate(44100)
        out_f.writeframesraw(data)
```

Check the header of the WAV file:

```
with wave.open("sound.wav", "rb") as in_f:
    print(repr(in_f.getparams()))
```

It should print something like `_wave_params(nchannels=1, sampwidth=2, framerate=44100, nframes=220500, comptype='NONE', compname='not compressed')`